# How to have nested Spring Boot applications added as dependencies to another Spring Boot application ignored?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have two Spring Boot applications, to be more precise, the one is a Spring YARN application (currently for my tests, I use the one from [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic-single/)), and another one which is meant to provide a REST interface. I want to be able to submit the YARN application to my Hadoop cluster via the REST interface. So I added the Spring YARN application as a dependency to my REST application. Now I have the problem that when I start my REST application, the Spring YARN client is found, too, which causes it to be started, and that fails as expected.
My question is now: How can I tell Spring Boot's `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to ignore the Spring YARN application?

I tried the following things without success:

- Specified the base packages in `@ComponentScan` (they are disjoint for both applications)
- tried to exclude classes the Spring YARN application tries to initialize as of `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=...)`

  - the main class of my Spring YARN application
  - `CommandYarnClient.class`
  - `SpringYarnClientConfiguration.class`
- specified different profiles to be active - `yarn` for my Spring YARN application and `rest` for my REST application

Is what I am trying to do impossible, or is there some trick behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

The [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle) directed me to the solution. If you more thoroughly read the section on [Gradually replacing auto-configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-replacing-auto-configuration) you can find there:

> If you need to find out what auto-configuration is currently being applied, and why, starting your application with the `--debug` switch. This will log an auto-configuration report to the console.

I did this, and saw that the startup process tried to execute the `YarnClientAutoConfiguration`, so I changed my auto-configuration line to

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = YarnClientAutoConfiguration.class)
```

and voila, I got what I wanted.